# Vectorizing R custom calculation with dynamic day range

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, lapply

I have a big dataset (around 100k rows) with 2 columns referencing a device_id and a date and the rest of the columns being attributes (e.g. device_repaired, device_replaced).

I'm building a ML algorithm to predict when a device will have to be maintained. To do so, I want to calculate certain features (e.g. device_reparations_on_last_3days, device_replacements_on_last_5days).

I have a function that subsets my dataset and returns a calculation:

- For the specified device,
- That happened before the day in question,
- As long as there's enough data (e.g. if I want last 3 days, but only 2 records exist this returns NA).

Here's a sample of the data and the function outlined above:

```
data = data.frame(device_id=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,10))
                  ,day=c(1:5,1:10)
                  ,device_repaired=sample(0:1,15,replace=TRUE)
                  ,device_replaced=sample(0:1,15,replace=TRUE))


# Exaxmple: How many times the device 1 was repaired over the last 2 days before day 3 
# => getCalculation(3,1,data,"device_repaired",2)
getCalculation <- function(fday,fdeviceid,fdata,fattribute,fpreviousdays){

    # Subset dataset
    df = subset(fdata,day<fday & day>(fday-fpreviousdays-1) & device_id==fdeviceid)

    # Make sure there's enough data; if so, make calculation
    if(nrow(df)<fpreviousdays){
        calculation = NA
    } else {
        calculation = sum(df[,fattribute])
    }

    return(calculation)
}
```

My problem is that the amount of attributes available (e.g. device_repaired) and the features to calculate (e.g. device_reparations_on_last_3days) has grown exponentially and my script takes around 4 hours to execute, since I need to loop over each row and calculate all these features.

I'd like to vectorize this logic using some *apply* approach which would also allow me to parallelize its execution, but I don't know if/how it's possible to add these arguments to a lapply function.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) and [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) by hadley? HTH

Comment: You basically use only computations on a data frame. I think you should use package **data.table** to speedup these computations (and particularly the subsetting). Yet, I don't know **data.table** enough to give you the answer.

Comment: Also note that `apply` is not really a vectorized approach in the sense of the number of calls/performance.